# Attach table data in email using IICS

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement on, When the job fails, we are storing that details in a table and can we send a mail using IICS with a screenshot or the file attachement of the table rows. (considering 10 rows max).

Is that possible in IICS.

Any Suggestions to achieve it.

thanks.

Comment: can you not out put the data into a file using a session and send that file through e-mail.

Comment: yup, generate a file, use it as attachement